# How to disable/override Windows 10 Hotkeys with C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, hotkeys

I'm trying to register certain hotkeys, but I can't because they are Windows defaults.

```
CTRL+WIN+1 minimizes the current window. I'd like it to do something else.
I'd like to completely disable WIN+LEFT/RIGHT.
I'm also trying to handle the CTRL+WIN+Arrow in my own virtual desktop manager.
```

[zVirtualDesktop](https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop)

This has to be done using c# and Win32 API if necessary. It absolutely cannot use Autohotkey.

Every page I find descibes how this can be done with AutoHotKey.

I'd post code, but I really don't know where to start. I use Win32 to register hotkeys. I assume there is a way to override them, but I can't find any info.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is this an example of a _[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)_?   Are you trying to create a kiosk application?

Comment: No, on a personal level, I can't stand WIN+LEFT/RIGHT. Also, I'm working on this...https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Comment: I took the code down for now. I might put it back up. All the commits are still there.

Comment: I seriously cannot find any info other than AHK and I need to use C#. I didn't know where else to post this. I'm sure this question will get hit by curious people.

Comment: I understand that I'm lacking stuff here. The obstacle I face is clearly stated and I've searched everywhere except AHK source code.

Comment: You might be able to install a global keyboard hook and gobble up the key as it comes along?

Comment: That might be the only approach and is probably what AHK is doing.

Comment: @MickyD I totally see why you asked if i was making a kiosk. lol. I just found this....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260744/how-do-you-disable-system-hotkeys-in-user32-dll/43303029#43303029

Comment: Oh lol.  I wasn't snooping on you :)   EDIT: Ohh you just answered that other question too.  Nice one :)

Comment: oh I just figured you thought I was that guy and just creating a new account or something. Anyway, you were right about the keyboard hook.

Comment: Not a problem good sir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do this using a keyboard hook. A good hook class for this can be found on this  [CodeProject Article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7294/processing-global-mouse-and-keyboard-hooks-in-c)

Using the below code will prevent the <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> from occurring. You can use this to override whichever keys you'd like.

This will even override hotkeys which you added via `RegisterHotKey` Win API.

Once you have those classes in your project you can add handlers to the static `HookManager` class like below.

```
//It's worth noting here that if you subscribe to the Key_Press event then it will break the international accent keys.
HookManager.KeyPress += HookManager_KeyPress;
HookManager.KeyDown += HookManager_KeyDown;
HookManager.KeyUp += HookManager_KeyUp;
```

You can also add mouse events, but for simplicity I'm just showing the keyboard hook.

I've also created a generic list so that I know which keys are currently down and I remove those keys from the list on the `KeyUp` event.

```
public static List<Keys> keysDown = new List<Keys>();
private static void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys
            if(keysDown.Contains(e.KeyCode) == false)
            {
                keysDown.Add(e.KeyCode);
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && WIN())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                //Do what you want when this key combination is pressed
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && WIN())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                //Do what you want when this key combination is pressed
            }

        }

        private static void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys
            while(keysDown.Contains(e.KeyCode))
            {
                keysDown.Remove(e.KeyCode);
            }
        }

        private static void HookManager_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys

        }

        public static bool CTRL()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LControlKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RControlKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.Control) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.ControlKey))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool SHIFT()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RShiftKey) ||
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.Shift) ||
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.ShiftKey))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool WIN()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LWin) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RWin))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool ALT()
    {
        //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
        if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.Alt) ||
            keysDown.Contains(Keys.LMenu) ||
            keysDown.Contains(Keys.RMenu))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, how is everything progressing. Any progress on the solution? Thank you very much